# Who is corpus annotator

Tags: computational-linguistics, corpora

I'm a beginner of nlp.
I'm wondering who is annotator of corpus usually ?
Who does actually do works of annotating ? Researchers?

Comment: corpus anotation is 'the practice of adding interpretative linguistic information to a corpus’ (Leech 2005) - linguistic or interpretative info. The product is a value-added corpus.

Comment: ok. I understood that, but I wonder 'who' are  actual annotators which do works.

Comment: Some linguists or otherwise informed people, am I wrong? What sort of an answer do you expect?

Comment: Thanks to answering. Very helpful. But, first comment you added answer not who is corpus annotator but what is corpus annotation. However I appreciate that your second comment answers the former.

Comment: Most often, they are students hired for part-time jobs and given instructions on how to annotate.

Comment: I really wanted to know a  kind of your information. So, about corpus which is annotated by part-timer, its total cost for making can be calculated ? Whrere can I know costs of corpus building ?

Comment: I sold a big text file for $100 for a corpus created by a Russian Finnish linguist. The prices vary, don't they? ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's often linguistics students who are working towards their PhD.

Answer (score 2):

In a manner of speaking, a corpus annotator can be a programme, called lemmatizer or PoS tagger which tag text corpora automatically based on trained data which were tagged manually by people.

Answer (score 0):

For those people who have ambitious aims for NLP. If you want to reveal secret insights from your corpus, you need to work on it. Supervised learning is mostly used for labeling your features. Then thanks to some ML algorithms you are creating model that is suitable for your work. At that point, you need someone/people to label your corpus. Annotators are taking stepping in that stage.